# Design pattern for properties and static constructor

Tags: c#, properties, constructor, static

I have a base class with static properties and a static constructor. Now when I create a derived instance I want those properties to be isolated to that instance (non-static). How can I solve this?

Comment: You cannot derive anything that is static. That is what static means.

Comment: Don't make it static?!

Comment: I already have all this code with this setup. I need a pattern to refactor it to.

Comment: Wow, I wonder how low rating this question can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok answering my own question. So I managed to solve it this way:

```
public abstract class IntegrationTestBase
{
    private static bool _constructed;

    protected IntegrationTestBase()
    {
        if (_constructed)
        {
            lock (Lock)
            {
                AssignNonStaticProperties();
            }

            return;
        }

        _constructed = true;

        // Do the stuff which was originally in the static constructor, runs only once
        ...
    }
}
```

Doing this I also had to make a bunch of methods non-static. I also had some problems with `[ClassInitialize]` which must be used on a static method. So I changed these to a default constructor with a `_constructed` bool aswell.

Answer (score 1):

*Updated answer to match updated question.*

To access the static properties through the instance class you could simply use something like:

```
class SomeClass
{
    private static string staticFoo;

    public string Foo
    {
        get { return SomeClass.staticFoo; }
    }
}
```

Static constructors however are something different. You cannot call them manually, and they are called once automatically when the first instance is created or static member is referenced.
[More info on static constructors on MSDN.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx)

**Updated for comment:**

I think this is the closest to what you want.

```
class SomeClass
{
    private static string staticFoo;

    private string instanceFoo;

    public SomeClass()
    {
        instanceFoo = staticFoo; // Assign the instance variable.
    }

    public static string StaticFoo // Static property.
    {
        get { return staticFoo; }
    }

    public string Foo // Instance property.
    {
        get { return instanceFoo; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats true, my fault, class is not static. Updated my question.

Comment: Nice, although that will only give me the static value and for the instance I would like a non-static value so that my parallel code execution does not blend

Comment: Then you should assign it upon instantiation, that way it copies the value and the static value does not influence it after the instance is created

Comment: Yes, something like that. The uninstantiated property should return a static, and the instantiated should return a non-static. How could that be done?

Comment: I updated my answer. One question though: why would you even want to use both a static and an instance version of a class? I can't think of any good use cases for that.

Comment: Yes your answer requires that I use two different properties, I see. I'm using the setup for a base class for integration tests. The static constructor is there to create an environment (database generation and so on) for the tests to run in. It thereby uses the static properties to generate data. The tests then use the same properties (and associated methods) to create extra data. For exampel, CreateCustomer. The environment should only be created once for a test suite, regardless of the number of tests executed. Hence the static constructor.

Comment: Of course it requires 2 properties because that is simply how c# and static/instance classes work. If you did not know that you should really read up on your oo-programming...

Answer (score 1):

The best would be for you to change the base class to not have static properties. If you want them to be instance specific, don't make them static.

If you cannot change the base class you can create new properties in your subclass and copy the values of the static properties of the base class to your non-static properties in the subclass constructor, and then use the subclass properties instead of the static base class properties.

However if you have existing code you cannot change that is using the base class static properties, and you are hoping to somehow coerce the static properties to no longer be static, then you are out of luck.

Comment: What if I make the properties non-static, add a non-static constructor to the base class which calls the non-static properties, and a static flag which is checked by the non-static constructor so that it is only executed once?

Comment: @Drutten that could work. Put a lock around checking the flag and initializations to ensure it does indeed only get done once (in case you potentially have many threads running through it at the same time).

Comment: Thanks! It works and I put a nice lock to ensure thread safety. Now there is only the problem with ClassInitialize being static. Maybe I have to solve that one with a flag aswell (bummer since I have 100s of them).